# AS3 Modify a variable set in the root timeline from a class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, variables

I'm fairly new to Action Script 3 and I have a variable within my root timeline on a frame to set the speed of the character for my game:

```
var userSpeed:Number = 2;
```

Now, I have a class for my shooting and I have added a hit test so that when I shoot a power up it changes the speed to 4 (double the default), however since this is inside my class, I was wondering how I can modify the variable from here within the class.

```
if(this.hitTestObject(speedPower) || this.x < 0 || this.x > stage.stageWidth || this.y < 0 || this.y > stage.stage.height)
{
this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveShot);
this.parent.removeChild(thisshootTurret);
this.parent.userSpeed = 4;
}
```

The way of accessing the variable was just a random guess, I couldn't find anything on the internet or questions here that fit my problem so it's all I could come up with.

The current way gives me this error:

```
1119: Access of possibly undefined property userSpeed through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.
```

and I get the same error when I try:

```
root.userSpeed = 4;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry my answer was wrong, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: It's fine, I just really need help with this, do you not have any idea how I can change that variable from my class?

Comment: `MovieClip(this.parent).userSpeed = 4`?

Comment: I think `this.parent.userSpeed = 4` should work. Although in general if you're going to modify `userSpeed` often you may want to put it in a global static class, so that all classes can access it easily.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help although I tried both of these and it didn't work. @Benoît when I used that, it didn't appear that I had any errors and then when I shot it, I think it said undefined property. I've updated the question now as I explained wrong, hope someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you define variable or function on timeline (regardless is it main timeline or timeline of particular `MovieClip`) they are added to the class associated (if any, it is not necessary to associate classes to every `MovieClip`) to `MovieClip` that owns timeline.

While main timeline is always associated to **Document Class** (Main class) and you create variable on main timeline, then you can use it directly in Main class's constructor, But take in account one important thing variables defined on timeline are not initialized until the frame where you assign value to them is executed.

from your code I'm guessing `this.parent` is reference on Main class - Document Class. If this is true then just use following code:

```
if(this.hitTestObject(speedPower) || this.x < 0 || this.x > stage.stageWidth || this.y < 0 || this.y > stage.stage.height)
{
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveShot);
    this.parent.removeChild(thisshootTurret);
    this.parent.userSpeed = 4; // You just access userSpeed variable because it 
                               // is member of Main class.
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I didn't explain correctly, I've updated my question now, I meant the root timeline, as in my Action Script is on a frame and I want to access the variable there from a class, not the "MainTimeline" as a class.

Answer (score 0):

Im also fairly new to AS3, and a bit late on the question, but here is what I learned about accessing root from within a class:

```
Movieclip(root).userSpeed = 4;
```

Should do the trick. You can also call root functions from within class:

```
Object(root).myfunction();
```

Never invoke root or parent from within your constuctor function, it will return null. You can use an Event.ADDED function and event handler to circumvent this.